# SET THEORY related problem

Tags: combinatorics

Let A, B, C are three sets such that $|A\cap B| = |(B \cap C)| = |(C \cap A)| = |(A \cap B \cap C)| = 2$, then $|((A \times B) \cap (B \times C))|$ is equal to

(A) 0

(B) 1

(C) 2

(D) 4

As per my understanding the number of common sub-set is 4 because $(A \cap B \cap C)$ has 2 element which is common to all hence this is the correct answer but I am not able to prove it using properties

Comment: Does $n(X)$ mean the number of elements of $X$?

Comment: To denote cardinality of a set $X$, use $|X|$.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

4 is correct. $$|((A\times B)\cap(B\times C))|=|((A\cap B)\times(B\cap C))=|(A\cap B)|\cdot |(B\cap C)|.$$

The first equality follows from the fact that the intersection of the cartesian products is the product of intersections, and then the cardinality of the cartesian product is equal to the product of the cardinality of the sets.

Comment: If the original question uses that notation, then I will use the same.

Comment: That is not my problem.

Comment: Alternative notation is not necessarily improper.

Comment: In this case it was obvious to me what that notation means. Note how the OP mentions that the intersection of the three sets has 2 elements and n of the intersection is 2. If it was c instead of n, it would be easy to deduce that it refers to cardinality (where n refers to number of elements). However, if it was for example p, I would not have made the "guess" that it refers to how many elements there are in the set.

Comment: The OP may not have been quick enough to answer the question before reading my answer, or whatever. Sure, they could have answered the question "what does n mean?", but that does not make the notation improper.  Maybe their school uses n instead of |-|, so it would be natural for them to assume n(-) is widely used. Who knows? Not me, nor am I interested in continuing on this matter.

Comment: With or without an admin, we have the ability to delete these comments.  I have deleted mine now that they are no longer relevant and I suggest you do the same.